# xml window blank for no reason in android studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, user-interface, ide

I updated my android studio to Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1. Unfortunately, my hompage .xml file is blank even I created a lot code on it from previos version. below is the problem happen with .xml file in my app. Can you help me how to overcome this issue. I don't know what error with it.
[image]

Comment: i have the same problem but with the layout preview, any solution???

Answer (score 0):

Try below points:

1. Invalidate caches/ Restart

   - Go to the file which is present in the top menu bar in Android Studio and then click on the option “Invalidate Caches/Restart…” present in the Dropdown.
2. Disable and then Enable android apk support

   - Go to settings that are present in the file,On the left side of the settings, find an option named plugin, click on the plugin and go to Installed which will show you the installed plugins. Scroll down and check for Android APK Support and disable the option. After disabling, click on Apply button and then ok. It would disable the use of Android APK Support in Android Studio. Now go back to the same settings and Check/Enable the same option which you disabled earlier. After doing that click on Apply and then the OK button.
3. After trying all the methods, and still not able to see the Layout, try to rebuild your project.